# Periodicity of a communicating class

Tags: markov-chains

> > Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov chain with discrete state space $E$ and transition matrix $P$. Let $C\subseteq E$ be a communicating class. Prove or disprove the following statement. $C$ is periodic with period $p>1$ if $C$ can be decomposed into a disjoint union of sets $C_0\cup\ldots\cup C_{p-1}$ in such a way that if $i\in C_n$ and $j\in C_m$ with $m\neq n+1\text{ mod }p$, then $p_{ij}=0$. Distinguish between the cases when (a) $E$ is finite, (b) $E$ is countably infinite.

--

Do not see why it is necesary to distinguish between (a) $E$ finite and (b) $E$ countably infinite.

Anyway:

Assume that $p(C)=1$. Then $p(i)=1$ for a $i\in C$. Fix $i\in C$ and use it as a reference point for the disjoint sets
$$
C_k:=\left\{j\in C| \exists~m\equiv k\text{ mod }p: p_{ij}^{(m)}>0\right\}.
$$
These sets build a decomposition as described in the task. Because of this decomposition
there exists exactly one $k\in\left\{0,1,...,p-1\right\}$ so that $p_{ii}^{(m)}>0$ for a $m\equiv k\text{ mod }p$.

Moreover it exists a $\tilde{n}\in\mathbb{N}$ so that $p_{ii}^{(n)}>0$ forall $n\geqslant\tilde{n}$, i.e.
$$
S:=\left\{\tilde{n},\tilde{n}+1,\tilde{n}+2,\ldots\right\}\subseteq R(i):=\left\{n>0|p_{ii}^{(n)}>0\right\}.
$$
Write $S$ as
$$
S=\bigcup_{k=0}^{p-1}\left\{\ell\in S|\ell\equiv k\text{ mod }p\right\}.
$$
Then $p_{ii}^{(s)}>0$ for all $s\in S$ implies that $i\in C_t$ for all $t\in\left\{0,1,...,p-1\right\}\setminus\left\{k\right\}$ contradicting that the sets $C_j, j\in\left\{0,1,...,p-1\right\}$ are disjoint.

So $p(C)>1$.

--- Again: Why is it necessary to distinguish between $E$ finite and $E$ countably infinite?

Comment: You know that all this is explained in detail in tons of online resources, do you?

Comment: You might want to check Norris, Markov chains. _(ed ajf)_

Comment: @Did I have this book but where is it in this book? I do not find it!

Comment: Try pages 18-20 [there](http://www2.math.uu.se/~takis/L/McRw/mcrw.pdf).

Comment: @Did Maybe you can say a word or two to my last edit?

Comment: What a thorough cleansing of the comments... OP: Did you ask for it? That the request was fulfilled was probably at least partly ill-advised because this thread of comments contained an analytical description of the problem with this OP's recent string of questions, equivalent to asking for the content of the first chapters of a book on the classical theory of Markov chains. Is this considered an undesirable message on math.SE?

Comment: 1. I did not ask to delete the comments. 2. What about my edit/ proof?

Comment: @Did I do not know exactly why you do not want to say a word to my edited proof.. I think it might be correct and therefore I would like to get a feedback to my efforts. Moreover I would like to know wh it is necessary to distinguish between $E$ finite and $E$ countably infinite, because the proof that I gave holds for both cases as far as I am able to see.

Answer (score 1):

The following hints might be useful (in case my interpretation of your proof is correct).

I'm afraid your approach is *not ok* and this is presumably the reason that it seems not necessary to distinguish between a finite state space $E$ and a countably infinite $E$.

First let us formulate the proposition conveniently and then analyse it's logical structure.

> **Proposition:** Let $(X_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}_0}$ be a Markov chain with discrete state space $E$ and transition matrix $P$. Let $C\subseteq E$ be a communicating class. Assume
>
> - (i) $\ C$ can be decomposed into a disjoint union of sets $C_0\cup\ldots\cup C_{p-1}$ in such a way that if $i\in C_n$ and $j\in C_m$ with $m\neq n+1\text{ mod }p$, then $p_{ij}=0$.
> - (ii) $\ C$ is periodic with period $p>1$
>
> then
>
> \begin{align*}
> (\text{i})\Rightarrow(\text{ii})
> \end{align*}
>   Distinguish between the cases when (a) $E$ is finite, (b) $E$ is countably infinite.

---

Since your proof starts with:

> Assume that $p(C)=1$. Then $p(i)=1$ for a $i\in C\ldots$

It seems you want to proof the proposition *indirectly* by showing that

> $$\neg (\text{ii}) \Rightarrow \neg (\text{i})$$

The final argument of your proof is pointing out a contradiction according to the sets $C_j,j\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ by showing that they are not disjoint, although they should be disjoint.

> I think there are two problems using this argumentation.
>
> **(1)** Since (i) is of the form $\exists(\text{i}.0):(\text{i}.1 \Rightarrow \text{i}.2)$ with
>
> - (i.$0$) $\ C$ can be decomposed into a disjoint union of sets $C_0\cup\ldots\cup C_{p-1}$ in such a way that
> - (i.$1$) $\ $if $i\in C_n$ and $j\in C_m$ with $m\neq n+1\text{ mod }p$
> - (i.$2$) $\ $then $p_{ij}=0$

Observe, the negation of $(\text{i})$ is the negation of $\exists(\text{i}.0):\left(\text{i.1}\Rightarrow\text{i.2}\right)$ and therefore we have to show

$$\forall(\text{i}.0):\left(\text{i.1} \wedge \neg \text{i.2}\right)$$

So, in order to show $\neg (\text{i})$ we have to show that:

> *For all* decompositions of $C$ into a disjoint union of sets $C_0\cup\ldots\cup C_{p-1}$ there are $n_0,m_0\in\{0,1,\ldots,p-1\}$ with $m_0\neq n_0+1\text{ mod }p$ and $i_0,j_0\in E$ with  $i_0\in C_{n_0}$ and $j_0\in C_{m_0}$ so that $p_{i_0j_0}>0$.

**Conclusion:** Since your argumentation is different, you do not show the negation of $(i)$.

> **(2)** Your approach with $p=1$ gives right from the beginning
>
> \begin{align*}
> C_k:=&\left\{j\in C| \exists~m\equiv k\text{ mod }p: p_{ij}^{(m)}>0\right\}\\
> =&\left\{j\in C| \exists~m\equiv k\text{ mod }1: p_{ij}^{(m)}>0\right\}\\
> =&\left\{j\in C| \exists~m\equiv 0\text{ mod }1: p_{ij}^{(m)}>0\right\}\\
> =&C
> \end{align*}
>
> So, in fact your proof analyses always only the *trivial* decomposition $C=C_0$ which was presumably not your intention.

---

**Note:** I was also curious why we should differ between the *finite* and the *countably infinite* state space $E$. One reason could be, that a *constructive proof* for the finite case dealing with a finite transition matrix $P$ can't be easily generalised to a *countably infinite* transition matrix.

I found in [Finite Markov Processes and Their Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00LIFOX18) section 2.4.5 from *Marius Iosifescu* an instructive example how to constructively determine the period of a Markov Chain.

There he points to a *downloadable* book from *R.B.Ash*: [Basic Probability Theory](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~r-ash/BPT/BPT.pdf).
You might want to have a look at chapter 7, Theorem 10, which is strongly related to your question. You might also want to have a look at chapter 7, example 2, which determines the period for a Markov chain with a *finite* state space. Finiteness is necessary there in order to terminate the constructive approach.

**Note:** According to the comments to your question I had a look at [Markov Chains](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521633966) from *R. Norris*. I think that Theorem 1.8.4 on page 43 is the only one, which has a strong connection to your question.