# Equivalent statements about transition matrix of a Markov chain

Tags: markov-chains

> > Let $P=(p_{ij})_{i,j\in E}$ be a transition matrix and $E$ of finite cardinality. Show that the following three conditions are equivalent: (i) $p$ is irreducible and aperiodic. (ii) $P^n$ is irreducible. (iii) There exists a $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p_{ij}^{(n)}>0$ for every $i,j\in E$.

**Edit**

In a book I found an understandable proof for (i$)\implies$ (iii), see [here](http://books.google.de/books?id=LATJdzBlajUC&pg=PA22&lpg=PA22&dq=irreducible%20aperiodic%20markov%20chain&source=bl&ots=zO7RleFpQ3&sig=KuHof4EahQvIcIHQ8JpDqfTfGak&hl=de&sa=X&ei=8fpZVKDzG5fkaoLBguAL&ved=0CCAQ6AEwADge#v=onepage&q=irreducible%20aperiodic%20markov%20chain&f=false).

To be honest, I do not know how to prove the rest and so I need your help, please.

I do not know which implications hold, too and - what is the biggest problem - how to prove them in order to have in the end, that all three statements are indeed equivalent.

So it would be great to get help from you.

Comment: A transition matrix determines a the Markov chain. Irreducible means that all states communicate with each other. So a transition matrix is irreducible if $p_{ij}^n>0$ for some $n\geq 0$ for all $i,j.$ In other words, it is possible to go from state $i$ to $j$ within $n$ steps and also from $j$ to $i$ since this holds for all $i,j$ and so $i$ and $j$ are Connected.

Comment: Same remark as [there](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1001553).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's first introduce the terms and definitions  together with some motivation we need in order to prove the equivalency of the statements.

> *Irreducibility* and *aperiodicity* are conditions of central importance in Markov theory, since they play a key role in the study of *stationary distributions*.
>
> **Irreducibility** is, loosely speaking, the property that *all states of the Markov chain can be reached from all others*. More precise:
>
> Let $E=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ the *state space* and $P=(p_{i,j})_{i,j\in E}$ the *transition matrix* of a *Markov chain* $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$. We say that a state $i$ **communicates** with another state $j$, symbolically $i\longrightarrow j$, if the chain has *positive probability* of ever reaching $i$ when we start from $j$. In other words, $i$ communicates with $j$, if there exists an $n$ such that
>   $$P(X_{m+n}=i|X_m=j)>0$$
>   If $i\longrightarrow j$ and $j\longrightarrow i$, then we say the states $i$ and $j$ **communicate**, and write
>   $$i\longleftrightarrow j$$.

This takes us directly to *irreducibility*:

> A Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with state space $E=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and transition matrix $P$ is said to be **irreducible** if for all $i,j\in E$ we have that $i\longleftrightarrow j$. Otherwise the chain is said to be **reducible**.

**Note 1:** An easy way to verify that a Markov chain is irreducible is to look at its transition graph, and check that from each state there is a sequence of arrows leading to any other state.

**Note 2:** Communication $i\longleftrightarrow j$ of states $i,j$ is an *equivalence relation* on $E$ and thus partitions $E$ into *communication classes*. So, a Markov chain or transition matrix $P$ is called irreducible if $E$ consists of a single class. This also explains the term *reducible*, since the analysis of the long-term behavior of a Markov chain can then be reduced to the analysis of the long-term behavior of one or more Markov chains with smaller state space.

Next let's consider the concept of *aperiodicity*.

> **Aperiodicity**: The **period** $d(i)$ of a state $i\in E$ is defined as the greatest common divisor of the set of times that the chain can return (i.e., has *positive probability* of returning) to $i$, given that we start with $X_0=i$. If $d(i)=1$, then we say that the state $i$ is **aperiodic**. A Markov chain is said to be **aperiodic**, if all its states are aperiodic. Otherwise the chain is said to be **periodic**.

**Note 3:** Consider for instance a weather situation. It's easy to check that regardless of whether the weather today is rain or sunshine, we have for any $n$ that the probability of having the same weather $n$ days later is strictly positive. This is clearly a situation of a Markov chain which is *aperiodic*.

**Note 4:** Period is a class property: *If the states $i$ and $j$ communicate, then they have the same period. (see e.g. Theorem 4.2 from [Markov Chains - Gibbs Fields, Monte Carlo Simulation and Queues](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985093) from Pierre Brémaud). We can therefore speak of *the period of a communication class* or of *the period of an irreducible Markov chain*.

**Note 5:** For each communication class the period $d$ of it defines a *unique partition* of $E$ into $d$ classes $C_0, C_1, \ldots, C_{d-1}$ such that for all $k$ with $i\in C_{k}$,
$$\sum_{j\in C_{k+1}}p_{i,j}=1,$$
where by convention $C_d=C_0$, and where $d$ is maximal. (see e.g. Theorem 4.1 in Pierre Brémaud's book).

> We further assume that the following theorem about aperiodic Markov chain is known: (see e.g. Theorem 4.1 from [Finite Markov Chains and Algorithmic Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521890012))
>
> *Theorem 1:* Suppose that we have an aperiodic Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with state space $E=\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and transition matrix $P$. Then there exists an $N<\infty$ such that 
>   $$p^{(n)}_{i,i}>0$$
>   for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and all $n\geq N$.

---

> **The Proposition:**

I assume the proposition is slightly different as it is stated by the OP. So, here I prove the following:

> The following statements are equivalent:
>
> (i) A Markov chain $(X_n)_{n\geq 0}$ with transition matrix $P=(p_{i,j})_{i,j\in E}$ is irreducible and aperiodic
>
> (ii) There exists an $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $P^n$ is irreducible for all $n \geq N$
>
> (iii) There exists an $N\in\mathbb{N}$ such that $p^{(n)}_{i,j}>0$ for every $i,j\in E$ and for all $n \geq N$

---

> **The Proof:**
>
> (i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii)
>
> By the assumed aperiodicity and theorem 1 above, there exists an integer $N<\infty$ such that $p^{(n)}_{i,i}>0$ for all $i\in\{1,\ldots,k\}$ and all $n\geq N$. Fix two states $i,j\in E$. By the assumed irreducibility, we can find some $n_{i,j}$ such that $p^{(n_{i,j})}_{i,j}>0$. Let $M_{i,j}=N+n_{i,j}$. For any $m\geq M_{i,j}$, we have
>
> \begin{align*}
> P(X_m=j|X_0=i)&\geq P(X_{m-n_{i,j}}=i,X_m=j|X_0=i)\\
> &=P(X_{m-n_{i,j}}=i|X_0=i)P(X_{m}=j|X_{m-n_{i,j}}=i)\tag{1}\\
> &>0
> \end{align*}
>
> The first factor in (1) is positive because $m-n_{i,j}\geq N$, and the second is positive by the choice of $n_{i,j}$. Hence, we have shown that $p^{(m)}_{i,j}>0$ for all $m\geq M_{i,j}$. The claim now follows with
>   $$M=max\{M_{1,1},M_{1,2},\ldots,M_{1,k},M_{2,1},\ldots,M_{k,k}\}.$$
>   (iii) $\Rightarrow$ (ii)
>
> This is only a rephrasing of (iii).
>
> So, let's assume (iii) is valid. Then for $n\geq N$ and for any $i,j\in E$ 
>   $$p^{(n)}_{i,j}>0\quad\text{and}\quad p^{(n)}_{j,i}>0\qquad\Longrightarrow\qquad p^{(n)}_{i,j}\longleftrightarrow p^{(n)}_{j,i}$$
>   Since all $p^{(n)}_{i,j}$ are in only one communciation class $P^n$ is irreducible and (ii) follows.
>
> (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i)
>
> We show $\neg (\text{i}) \Rightarrow \neg (\text{ii})$.
>
> Let's first assume $P$ is *reducible*. This implies according to note 2 above, that the number of partitions of communication classes is greater than one. So, for any $i,j\in E$ which are in different communication classes $p^{(n)}_{i,j}=0$ for all $n\geq N(\in \mathbb{N})$ and $\neg(\text{ii})$ follows.
>
> Suppose now that $P$ is *irreducible* but has period $d>1$. In this case the state space splits according to note 5 into $d$ sets, $C_0,\ldots,C_{d-1}$, such that the Markov chain always moves from $C_k$ to $C_{k+1}$ (or $C_{d-1}$ to $C_0$).
>
> The transition matrix $P$ has a block structure with blocks $A_0$ to $A_{d-2}$ above the main diagonal and a block $A_{d-1}$ at the lower left side of $P$. Each of the blocks $A_k$ corresponds to the transitions from the cycle $C_k$ to $C_{k+1}$.
>
> Observe, that each further multiplication with $P$ implies a block-shifting until we reach $P^d$, which has a **block-diagonal** form corresponding to the cyclic classes $C_0,C_1,\ldots,C_{d-1}$. Therefore the $P$-cylic classes $C_0,C_1,\ldots,C_{d-1}$ are all in **different $P^d$-communication classes** as the diagonal block structure shows. Since this diagonal block-structure holds for all powers of $P^{d}$ $\neg(\text{ii})$ follows.

---

> **Note:** Most of the notes above and the proof for (i) $\Rightarrow$ (iii) come from Olle Häggström's nice (and small) book [Finite Markov Chains and Algorithmic Applications](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0521890012).
>
> The second part of the proof from (ii) $\Rightarrow$ (i) (namely assuming period $d>1$) can be found in chapter I, section 4.2 in Pierre Brémaud's [Markov Chains - Gibbs Fields, Monte Carlo Simulation and Queues](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0387985093).

Comment: @mathfemi: Hi, Miro! Thanks a lot for accepting my answer and granting the bounty! :-) Best regards, Markus